# В чем может быть проблема? ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Пытаюсь сделать helloworld RESTful web-service, но постоянно вылетает одна и та же ошибка: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer". Что я только не пробовал изменять и добавлять.
Использую Intellij Idea, server Tomcat 8.5.40

Структура проекта

[image]

Зависимости:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

web.xml:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UserService:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам пример взят [отсюда](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/)

Answer (score 1):

причина была в том, что нужен был Tomcat 9 версии